# Dialogflow+AWS Lambda Is it possible to return 2 more responses for 1 request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I use AWS Lambda as a webhook for my dialogflow.
One of my request requires some more time to be done and I want to tell the user, something like 'One moment...', next to process the request and when data will be available, return it.

In aws I use

```
context.succeed('one moment...')
... // processing this request, it takes 2-3 seconds
context.succeed('the result is ###')
```

But when I return **one moment** the connection is closing and my dialogflow doesn't get the result

Comment: You would need to make two request do deal with this. Just make the first request, and a second requests some seconds later to fetch the result.

Comment: I thought about this, but in this case I have to use dialogflow's API, not sure that web interface can send more then 1 request in sequence. Maybe is there solution to use something like promises or hold the session open after 1st response